# Is it accurate to say a baby is x inches taller or longer?

Tags: terminology

So today I was sending a picture of my new born to my British manager. I was saying that the baby looks a little bit different than the picture now he is 4 cm **taller**

She replied me saying *taller* or *longer*?

I didn't actually think about it before. I thought that taller will be the correct term as this is how we describe it as human beings ... Then I thought longer might be more accurate cause technically he cannot stand erect!

Which term is more accurate? Thanks for your insight

PS: I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Taller* would normally be used in talking about the height of adults, but, as babies can't stand, *longer* is more apporpriate.

Answer (score 1):

"Longer" evokes a thing for me ; "taller" either a person or a thing (tree, building ...) standing.

It is not the case for a baby.

Why not "bigger" ?

For amusement : Napoleon, who was short, could not reach a thing on too high a shelf. An officer helped him and said as a joke "I am greater than you, Sire". The answer was harsh : "You mean longer, Monsieur !".

Comment: But *bigger* could be in any dimension (perhaps expressed by weight).  Length is the term used in babies' growth charts in the UK, up to age 2 IIRC, so would seem appropriate.

Comment: @Chris H. You are right for the technical terms, "big" is three-dimensional, and "length" and "weight" are used by the nurses ; however, I would not imagine me saying "Congratulations ! However, how long is your baby ?" ; it is not sold by inches ... Moreover, the familiar expression "He is a big man" doesn't mean that is is overweight.

Comment: @MarkThorin, I agree but if you ask how big a baby is you're likely to get a weight though - that's the most common measurement.